# How to make background image height change depending on page content

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm having issues getting my background image to fill the screen, depending on the amount of page content. My app is made up of a main div and a side bar navigation. I have my background image styles set to the main div like so:

```
const styles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  backgroundStyle: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    padding: theme.spacing(3),
    height: '100vh',
    textAlign: 'center',
    backgroundImage: `url(${Background})`,
    backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
    backgroundPosition: "center center",
    backgroundSize: "cover",
    backgroundAttachment: "fixed",
    [theme.breakpoints.down('md')]: {
      height: '100%'
    }
  }
```

`height: '100vh'` works good until I select a navigation item that stretches beyond the view height, which cuts off the background image. Setting the height to `height: '100%'` fixes this but for a navigation item that doesn't have much content, the background image does not fill the entire screen. I having the same issues too when switching to a responsive view.

I set up a conditional to handle this:

```
return <main className={navListItem === 'Topic1' ? backgroundStyle : backgroundStyle2 }>
```

But it feels like I'm repeating myself because I'm creating another class called backgroundStyle2 that contains all the same styles only height is set to '100%' instead of '100vh'

I'm thinking there has to be an easier way to make the background image change depending on page the content besides using '100%' or '100vh' but I can't figure it out

Comment: You can use `minHeight:100vh ; height: 100%` . Did you try it ?

Comment: You're a genius. That works. I think I tried everything BUT that

Comment: Glad i could help. I also added this as an answer so it's more visible to future users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have at least 100vh height but also to extend that height according to the content if the content's height is greater than the viewport height, you should use `minHeight:100vh; height:100%`

```
const styles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  backgroundStyle: {
  flexGrow: 1,
  padding: theme.spacing(3),
  height: '100%',
  minHeight:'100vh',
  textAlign: 'center',
  backgroundImage: `url(${Background})`,
  backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
  backgroundPosition: "center center",
  backgroundSize: "cover",
  backgroundAttachment: "fixed",
  [theme.breakpoints.down('md')]: {
    height: '100%'
  }
}
```